# Passing the string parameter to the SendDlgItemMessage

Tags: c++, windows, string, win32gui

SendDlgItemMessage() function for its last parameter take an explicit string such as L"TEST" and when I pass it a string or wstring variable it does not work at all;

if I write below code it does not add any string item to my LIST_BOX :

```
string str[10];
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
   str[i] = "Item " + i;
int index2 = SendDlgItemMessage(hdlg, IDC_LIST2, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str[MarkerNumber ]);
```

Can you help me to set this function for using string parameters?

Comment: You need to get the raw C-string from it: i.e. you need to call `str[i].c_str()` to get the `char*` or `wchar_t*` that the API is looking for

Comment: Check your code - you using variable i out of scope.

Comment: That code won't *compile*, much less execute with success. That isn't how you build a string with running integer suffix, and I can all-but-assure you `"Item " + i` isn't doing what you think it is. Regarding the actual call to set the item text, your array is of `string`, not `wstring`. `SendDlgItemMessageA(hdlg, IDC_LIST2, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str[i].c_str());`, but you need to generate the string correctly *first*.

Comment: @Sergey I edited that;) here I write it wrong. in code it was true.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the API function `SendDlgItemMessage` doesn't know how to pass a `std::string` or `std::wstring` object. What you need to do is pass it the contained raw C-string within the string. You can do that by using the member function `std::string::c_str()` (which returns a `const char*` or `std::wstring::c_str()` which returns a `const wchar_t*`.

You can then use that as follows:

```
std::wstring szTest( L"Test String" );
int iIndex = SendDlgItemMessage( hDlg, IDC_LIST2, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)szTest.c_str() );
```

However, as it stands at the moment your code will not even compile; there are scope errors and there is no conversion from `std::string` to `LPARAM` and so the cast is invalid. Moreover, when you are constructing your strings (which you presumably want to be `"Item n"` where `n` ranges over [1...10], you should do it as follows:

```
for( int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i )
{
     szStringArray[i] = L"Item " + std::to_wstring(i);
}
```